# Are exceptions fundamental, or can they be replaced with conditions?

Tags: exception, language-agnostic

I am attempting to understand from where exception conditions derive. My question is at the end, but I will present an example that might make it clearer.

---

Take this Java code, for example. It has the path to a file and set-up a `File` object. If the path is null, an exception is thrown.

```
String path = getPathName();
try {
    File file = new File(path);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // ...
}
```

This is hardly an exceptional circumstance, though, and if we could modify it in such a way that this might be preferrable:

```
String path = getPathName();
if (path == null) {
    path = DEFAULT_PATH;
}
File file = new File(path); # we've removed the need for an exception
```

But moving further, we run into a new exception when we try and make the `File` readable.

```
try {
    file.setReadable(true);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // ...
}
```

We can skirt around this issue by checking two conditions:

```
SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
if (sm != null && sm.checkWrite(path)) {
    // modify the SecurityManager
} else {
    file.setReadable(true);
}
```

With this example in mind, on to my question...

---

If we move down the stack, going from Java to the OS, etc., is it possible to replace all exception handling code with if-else branches? Or is there some root cause of exceptions (hardware?) that means they are "baked" into programming?

Comment: The too broad option is checked. So, I guess someone was afraid this would have too many answers.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I could see the reasoning without voting for a close myself.

Comment: You can now *retract* Close Votes too which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If we move down the stack, going from Java to the OS, etc., is it possible to replace all exception handling code with if-else branches?

Yes. This is how it used to be done, and still is in languages without exceptions. Exceptions are used because they are easier in a number of senses. The primary advantages are that cases not anticipated by the programmer can be aggregated in a general handler; and that information about the exceptional condition does not need to be explicitly preserved in every single function until it is properly handled.

> Or is there some root cause of exceptions (hardware?) that means they are "baked" into programming?

Also yes. In general, unexpected hardware conditions need to be handled in some way, unless you are comfortable with undefined behaviour in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If *all* the methods in a program returned a pointer/reference to some kind of "exception" object (for other return values, pass in a pointer or reference to a caller-allocated storage location), and if every call to every method which might *directly or indirectly* want to throw an exception were bracketed with something like:

```
ret = callFunction( ...parameters...);
if (ret != NULL)
  return AddToExceptionStacktrace(ret, ...info about this call site... );
```

then there would be no need for any other form of exception handling (note that if the type supports scoped variables, the "return" statement would have to insert code to clean them up before it actually returns to the caller).

Unfortunately, that's a lot of extra code.  This approach would be workable in a language which had *only* "checked" exceptions (meaning a method can neither throw exceptions nor pass them through unless it is declared as doing so), but adding that overhead to every function which might directly or indirectly call a function which throws an exception would be very expensive.  Exception-handling mechanisms generally eliminate 99% of the extra overhead in the no-exceptions case, and the expense of increasing the overhead in the "exception" case.